# Two sensors, Is it possible to pause a sensor for a short time?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sensors, infrared

I have a code for saving data online. I have two IR sensors reading a door, one 6 inches from the other. If the first sensor goes off before the second, I know someone is entering the room, and the code sends a +1 to a file online. When the second sensor is triggered first, it means someone is leaving, so the system should pause and nothing should happen until the person moves out of both sensors. This last part isnt happening. How can I pause my first sensor when someone is leaving, so that I do not accidentally double my count?
           Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

from ubidots import ApiClient

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import os
import web

person_count = 0 
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%m-%d-%Y  %I:%M:%S')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN) #IR Sensor closest to Door
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN) #IR Sensor Farthest from Door
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT) #LED to indicate when data is being recorded to the web.
api = ApiClient("165c54954ee6d8f7324366495cab70217c7c3c91")
test_variable = api.get_variable("559c18cc76254214be90fe05")

while True:
    # If someone leaves, wait for one second.
    if GPIO.input(4) == 0 and GPIO.input(25) == 1:
            GPIO.output(17, False)
            time.sleep(2)

    # if both sensors are blocked, wait 1 second until clear
    elif GPIO.input(4) == 1 and GPIO.input(25) == 1:
            GPIO.output(17, False)
            time.sleep(2)

    # If neither sensor is blocked, wait 0.1 seconds.
    elif GPIO.input(4) == 0 and GPIO.input(25) == 0:
            GPIO.output(17, False)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    # If the first sensor (4) is blocked, send person count to Ubidots prog$
  elif GPIO.input(4) == 1 and GPIO.input(25) == 0:
            GPIO.output(17, True)
            person_count += 1
            test_value = person_count
            test_variable.save_value({'value':test_value})
            time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: What about if you have someone leaving and another entering at the same time?...you should record both states no?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour I could be mistaken but number 17 does that (exiting part) whereas 4 and 25 does entry. Mackenzie so if #4 is triggered you want 17 not to do the same to prevent double count correct?

Comment: @Leb when #4 is triggered, I recieve data. When #25 is triggered, I want to pause sensor pin #4.

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Please look at my edits, I have added comments. The pin 17 is an led that turns on when someone enters. This shows that I am recording data to the web. I am having a problem where when someone is leaving, data is still being recorded.

Comment: I am hoping that time.sleep() would allow for enough time for someone to exit the doorway before data starts collecting, but this is not the case. The time.sleep() functions are entirely being looked over. @Leb

Comment: @MackenzieRidley, I suggest that you add another checking code block under your first case `if` (which is for checking if someone is leaving the door) to `wait` until the IR sensor `4` is `blocked` that time you can say that the person has left the room. But here is the thing, this is not always the case, consider someone pass by IR sensor `25` but still didn't reach IR sensor `4` (between the two IR sensors) and then someone enters the room and block IR sensor `4` (closest to the door)...How are you going to treat it?...

Comment: Is each one sensor on its own script and communicate through a text file or are they all communicating from one python file.

Comment: @Leb They are communicating in the same file

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور thank you khalil. I have decided that the code's problem could be that everything under the "while True" portion is being ran at the same time. I will separate this further.

Comment: A solution to this, that you would need to test, is create a function for each of the sensors (`IR4(), IR17(), IR25()`) instead of including all them under an infinite loop statement. Within `IR4()` and `IR25()` create a variable (i.e. IR_global = 0) where when it's set to 1 it prevents the other function from being called and vice versa. I hope this isn't too vague.

Comment: @Leb I'm new to coding but that does make sense, and I will work on attempting that. Thank you both for the great advice! If you have any more suggestions please let me know